# FadeIn() alert-error not working in bootstrap3

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

Trying to fadeIn message to div with bootstrap 3 alert-error and hide classes but its not working. Same thing is working with bootstrap 2.3.2 is there any other method for bootstrap 3.

Html:

```
<div id="success" class="alert alert-success hide"></div><br>
<button type="submit" id="click" >Click</button>
```

JavaScript:

```
$("#click").click(function() {
    $("#success").html('Hello World!').fadeIn();
});
```

Bootstrap3 fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/MLpyH/

Bootstrap2.3.2 fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/e4SAK/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$("#success").html('Hello World!').removeClass("hide").hide().fadeIn("slow");
```

http://jsfiddle.net/MLpyH/11/

Comment: @AvinVarghese Now try

Comment: for showing the div? there is `slideDown`, you can use `animate` and change opacity

Comment: well that is the main purpose of that class afterall to hide :) !

Answer (score 0):

As of Bootstrap 3.0.1, the class `.hide` is [deprecated](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#helper-classes-show-hide) and replaced by `.hidden` or `.sr-only`:

```
<div id="success" class="alert alert-success hidden"></div>
```

Updating the answer by rps:

```
$("#success").html('Hello World!').removeClass("hidden").hide().fadeIn("slow");
```

(I didn't want to write an entirely new answer, but I'm not allowed to comment. Anyway, thank you, rps)